# Perl regex not able to match end of line

Tags: regex, perl

I am new in Perl. I am trying to extract VLAN information stored in file. File content,

```
VLAN0001
  Spanning tree enabled protocol rstp

Interface           Role Sts Cost      Prio.Nbr Type
------------------- ---- --- --------- -------- --------------------------------
PE8/1             Desg FWD 2         128.2945 P2p Edge 
Ta579               Desg FWD 3         128.5761 P2p Edge 

VLAN0023
  Spanning tree enabled protocol rstp

Interface           Role Sts Cost      Prio.Nbr Type
------------------- ---- --- --------- -------- --------------------------------
PE8/1             Desg FWD 2         128.2945 P2p Edge 
Ta579               Desg FWD 3         128.5761 P2p Edge    

ACCOUNT
  Spanning tree enabled protocol rstp

Interface           Role Sts Cost      Prio.Nbr Type
------------------- ---- --- --------- -------- --------------------------------
Ta579               Desg FWD 1         128.5764 P2p
```

I have perl code as,

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
my $filename = "spanning-tree1.txt";
    open my $fh, '<', $filename or die "error opening $filename: $!";
    my $data = do { local $/; <$fh> };

my @list = ($data =~ /(^[A-Za-z0-9]+.*?(?=^[A-Za-z0-9]+$|\Z))/msg);
#print Dumper($data);
#print "\n##############################################\n";
print Dumper(\@list);
```

And its out put is,

```
$VAR1 = [
          'VLAN0001
  Spanning tree enabled protocol rstp

Interface           Role Sts Cost      Prio.Nbr Type
------------------- ---- --- --------- -------- --------------------------------
PE8/1             Desg FWD 2         128.2945 P2p Edge
Ta579               Desg FWD 3         128.5761 P2p Edge

VLAN0023
  Spanning tree enabled protocol rstp

Interface           Role Sts Cost      Prio.Nbr Type
------------------- ---- --- --------- -------- --------------------------------
PE8/1             Desg FWD 2         128.2945 P2p Edge
Ta579               Desg FWD 3         128.5761 P2p Edge

ACCOUNT
  Spanning tree enabled protocol rstp

Interface           Role Sts Cost      Prio.Nbr Type
------------------- ---- --- --------- -------- --------------------------------
Ta579               Desg FWD 1         128.5764 P2p'
        ];
```

I need the output (`@list`) as,

```
$VAR1 = [
          'VLAN0001
  Spanning tree enabled protocol rstp

Interface           Role Sts Cost      Prio.Nbr Type
------------------- ---- --- --------- -------- --------------------------------
PE8/1             Desg FWD 2         128.2945 P2p Edge
Ta579               Desg FWD 3         128.5761 P2p Edge

',
          'VLAN0023
  Spanning tree enabled protocol rstp

Interface           Role Sts Cost      Prio.Nbr Type
------------------- ---- --- --------- -------- --------------------------------
PE8/1             Desg FWD 2         128.2945 P2p Edge
Ta579               Desg FWD 3         128.5761 P2p Edge

',
          'ACCOUNT
  Spanning tree enabled protocol rstp

Interface           Role Sts Cost      Prio.Nbr Type
------------------- ---- --- --------- -------- --------------------------------
Ta579               Desg FWD 1         128.5764 P2p'
        ];
```

**Interestingly I get proper values in `@list` when, input is given as a string and it is not read from file.**

Comment: Thanks to provide also **your perl code**

Comment: What is your expected result?

Comment: It's not empty, see: http://ideone.com/KT4lJa

Comment: @sputnick, Chankey Pathak, Updated the code. Please see this.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Your code wo0rks fine for me. There *cannot* be any difference between using a literal string and reading from a file unless your string doesn't match the file contents. Set `$Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1` so that you can see embedded control characters.

Comment: @Borodin, Yes it has windows control characters in file. I removed them it works very well.

Comment: What do you mean by *Windows control characters*? Removing them is a bit of a clunky solution unless you want to remove them anyway. If you publish the `Data::Dumper` output of the file contents then we can reproduce your situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can split whole string at beginning of the line followed by numbers and upper case letters,

```
my @list = split /(?= ^[A-Z0-9]+\s*$ )/mx, do { local $/; <DATA> };
```

Comment: We thought of doing like this, but there is no guarantee of this condition.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes regex are not the only solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;

my $inc = -1;
my @list;

my $filename = "spanning-tree1.txt";
open my $fh, '<', $filename or die "error opening $filename: $!";

while (<$fh>) {
    /^[A-Z0-9]+\s*$/ and $inc++;
    $list[$inc] .= $_;
}
print Dumper(\@list);
close $fh;
```

Comment: Dunno what you mean, the script read the file as expected. Have you verified the filename ? Having any error ?

Comment: File has control characters. I removed them and code works. Thanks.